# Windows sandboxing

Tags: java, c, windows, sandbox

We all know that when a sandbox runs, it does a few things before running the application. First, it creates a restricted token, this token restricts the "securable" objects the process can act on. Second, the sandbox spawns the child process with a low integrity level. Integrity levels are a feature of Windows Vista and above. A low integrity process can only edit a small area of the registry related to the applications settings.

My question is: Is it possible to run `Java` or `C` in the sandbox? Right now I am opening up cmd.exe and running java (for a file) but I have to disable the Alternative Desktop which opens the sandbox up to more attacks.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What specific software are you using to create your sandbox?